# Understanding LeakCanary memory leak stack trace

Tags: leakcanary

I have a simple news app and recently I started getting crash reports with OOM from some users(from Firebase Crashlytics). After some researches I found that the cause could be  caused by memory leak. So I installed LeakCanary and eventually while using the apo, I can see it reporting potential problem.

Can some experienced help me understand what is the problem? I have attached the log

Answer (score 0):

See https://square.github.io/leakcanary/fundamentals/#how-do-i-fix-a-memory-leak

Summary:

- Each node in the leak trace is a Java object and is either a class, an object array or an instance.
- Going down, each node has a reference to the next node. In the UI, that reference is in purple. In the Logcat representation, the reference is on the line that starts with a down arrow.
- At the top of the leak trace is a garbage-collection (GC) root. GC roots are special objects that are always reachable.
- At the bottom of the leak trace is the leaking instance. This instance was passed to RefWatcher.watch() to confirm it would be garbage collected, and it ended up not being garbage collected which triggered LeakCanary.
- The chain of references from the GC root to the leaking instance is what is preventing the leaking instance from being garbage collected. If you can identify the reference that should not exist at that point in time, then you can figure out why it’s incorrectly still set and then fix the memory leak.

Comment: I already came up to this post from the LeakCanary website, although I don't really get it